# how can I change the divider style in timepicker android for a more IOS style?

Tags: android, xml, timepicker

I want to create an IOS like timePicker in my android app, however I can't change the xml of the datePicker to have a thin horizontal line between spinner levels.
I tried making my own style but it doesn't even change the text size and font .
here's my timePicker.xml

```
<TimePicker
    android:id="@+id/datePicker1"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:timePickerMode="spinner"
    style="@style/pickerPersonnalizedUnpicked"
    app:barrierDirection="bottom"
    android:background="@color/beige_bg_rounded"
    android:fadingEdge="vertical"
   app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    android:calendarViewShown="false"/>
```

and my style :

```
 <style name="pickerPersonnalizedUnpicked">
    <item name="android:textSize">24sp</item>
    <item name="fontFamily">@font/poppins_semibold</item>
    <item name="android:textColor"> @color/unpicked</item>
</style>
```

what i want :
[image]

what I have so far :
[image]

I want the sepretor lines to be just like those in the ios version.
thank you

Comment: There are [many time picker libraries available for Android](https://android-arsenal.com/tag/27?sort=created). Perhaps there is one that offers what you seek.

Comment: not really, i can't personalize the seperators and the borders . I searched here but  i didn't find anything.

Comment: Then you may need to create your own. All of those are open source, so they can give you some implementation ideas.